# How to design objects for performance

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-architecture

Whilst reading a [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Game-Physics-Engine-Development-Commercial-Grade-ebook/dp/B00AQNVXFW) about physics engine development recently, I came across a design decision which I have never even considered before. This relates to the way the raw bytes in memory are addressed by the CPU.

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        /* Constructors and Methods */

    private:
        float padding;
}
```

The author claims that the padding, increasing the size of the object to a quad-word in x86 architecture, results in a noticeable benefit to performance. This is because 4 words sit more *cleanly* in memory than 3, what does this mean? Padding out an object with redundant data to increase performance seems pretty paradoxical to me.

This also begs another question, what about objects that are 1 or 2 words in size?
If my class is something like:

```
class Bar
{
    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        /* Constructors and Methods */

    private:
        /* padding ?? */
}
```

Should I add padding to this class so that it sits more *cleanly* in memory?

Comment: You should also look into data oriented design if you are interested in this.

Comment: In this particular case, it helps the compiler generating SIMD code more easily without shuffling. As for cache, this is a double-edged sword, and no single correct answer exists. Spanning several cache lines will eventually happen if your object size is not a power of two, and that may in theory be slower. In practice, it either doesn't matter because you process only one object anyway, or it doesn't matter because you process many objects serially, so the prefetcher has the adjacent cache line already fetched anyway. On the other hand, smaller objects take fewer cache lines.

Comment: If you don't mind compiler specific code (gcc and clang support this), you can also use [aligned](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes) attribute.

Comment: Sorry for double commenting, but apparently c++11 has a portable alternative, [alignas specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)

Comment: So where the object is said to sit more _cleanly_ in memory, does this refer to the cache lines in L1/L2(/L3) CPU cache? are they typically 4 words in width?

Comment: No. Cache lines are typically 64 or 128 bytes (most commonly 64). But 4*16 = 64 so four objects will fit a cache line nicely. Other than that, you can fetch 16 aligned bytes using a fast SSE instruction. Fetching _unaligned_ 16 bytes is much slower. Fetching 12 bytes is not possible. Thus, if the compiler uses SSE math, it must shuffle without padding. On the other hand, if your compiler generates "normal" scalar code, then 3 instead of 4 elements in the structure may very well be faster, since 25% less memory is touched, so the likelihood for a cache miss is 25% less, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the *compiler's* responsibility to decide what reasonable padding (assuming typical access patterns) is. The compiler does know a whole lot more about your machine than you'll ever will. Besides, your machine will be with you a couple of years; the program will be around for decades, running on a wide range of platforms, subject to a mind boggling variety of usage patterns. What is the best for today's i7 could very well be the worst for tomorrow's i8 or ARMv11.

Obfuscating code in pursuit of elusive "performance" falls squarely into [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Always remember that your time (writing, testing, debugging, understanding again after a week's time, on tweaked code) is much, much more expensive than the possibly wasted computer time (unless said code is run thousands of times a day on millions of machines, that is). Code tweaking makes no sense at all until you have hard facts showing that the performance isn't enough, and *measurements* telling you that shuffling that structure around is a bottleneck worth worrying about.

Comment: The compiler can be ill-equipped to make optimization decisions because the programming language does not provide a means to communicate some information known to the programmer. Some information can be discovered by the compiler but requires unusual effort (e.g., whole program analysis). Some information is input dependent (and even profile guided optimization may not do optimization that may be obvious to a programmer—e.g., which sort algorithm should be used). Padding need not be obfuscation but such optimization *is* likely to be fragile w.r.t. hardware, program, input, compiler changes.

Answer (score 3):

Processors doesnt "read" the memory byte by byte as humans, they process it chunk by chunk, of variable sizes depending of the processor. It's called memory access granularity;

By "memory aligning" your object, the acess time may be faster and you can also avoid data fragmentation.

You can read more about data alignement [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/)

Edit: I'm not saying that it's a good or bad practice, just sharing what I know about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two really important things to say in answer to this question.

First, if you're going to tweak code for performance benefits, and if you've decided it's worthwhile (for whatever reason), you **must** first write a benchmark. You must be able to try both and measure the difference.

Second, tweaks of this kind will depend on how the assembly language interacts with the hardware. You **must** be able to read assembly language code and understand the different instructions sets and hardware accessing modes in order to understand why these tweaks might work.

Finally, your question has no answer in isolation. It depends on whether those objects are allocated individually or are in collections; whether there are other objects next to them; and how the compiler generates code for each case. In all likelihood alignment on a power-of-two boundary will be faster than misalignment, but a collection that fits in a cache is faster than one that doesn't. I wouldn't expect padding 8 or 4 bytes to improve performance, but if it was important, I would try it and test the result.